# How to create a web design and actually implement it via exporting to HTML code

Tags: usability, website-design, ux-field

I know it takes skill to research and create a mockup design as a UX designer, but if you want to take it to the next level - what do you do? What platform do you use to actually realize it and actually get it out there? Do you code it manually or is there a more efficient way like Webflow to implement such designs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Framer" which is kind of similar to Figma but you can actually make responsive web pages there. You can also directly export your designs from Figma to Framer but i would recommend anyone & to you to actually learn Framer.
Anyways you can also use "Webflow", it's just that i personally like Framer more.